# Spring security generate a salted hash for users from command line

Tags: bash, command-line, spring-security, saltedhash

How do you generate a salted hash for users in spring security 3x from a bash command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security merges the password and salt in the format password{salt} instead of a simple concatenation of password+salt, from the terminal enter:

```
echo -n password{salt} | shasum -a 1
```

Please note: Spring security recommends using the encode method on PasswordEncoder

> If you want to generate encoded passwords directly in Java for storage in your user database, then you can use the encode method on the PasswordEncoder

[Source : Hashing and Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e3056)

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Boot CLI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-cli.html) provides a command for that. 
The [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-boot-cli) recomends its use.

```
spring encodepassword password
```